# Android application instance not created

Tags: android

I have an app which works on almost all devices. I have thousands of installations, no crashes. Now I have a friend who has a new Nexus 5 with Kit-kat. He uninstalled my app and installed it again. Now it crashes on every start.

It crashes because the start activity in its onCreate() method tries to access the application object which I have derived. But getApplication() does not return my instance of Application which I have defined in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

I have put some logs into the constructor and into the onCreate() method of my custom Application class. And these logs are not called. But only on this one phone!

Any ideas when an Application object is not created?

Comment: did you check your `manifest file`?

Comment: What do you mean by "check"? What should I look for? I have put my application class name there. And it works on almost all devices.

Comment: beside the point, that a simple reboot fixed your issue: please include the relevant snippets of your xml and code for the next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Restarting the phone solves the problem.

Seams to be a bug in Android.